# R keras freezes at first iteration

Tags: r, keras

I built a nn model with R keras sometimes ago which used to run finely. Yet since few weeks the script freezes at the first iteration.
This issue occurs on debian (version 5.6.14-2) with R (version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)) and keras (version 2.3.0.0). I tested it on windows and the code works.
Below is a very simplified code that produces this error:

```
library(keras)

generator2 <- function()
{
  return=function() {
    list(list(matrix(runif(100*11),100,11)), list(runif(100)))
  }
}

train_gen <- generator2()

k_reset_uids()
inp4<-layer_input(11)

out<-inp4%>%layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu')  %>% layer_dense(units = 1,activation='sigmoid',name="det")

model <- keras_model(inputs=c(inp4),outputs=list(out))

model %>% compile(optimizer=optimizer_rmsprop(),loss="mse")

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = 3,
  epochs = 3
)

>Epoch 1/3
>1/3 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0820
>####Then it freezes
```

Any hint ?

Comment: I'd start by verifying the inputs starting by the type and length of the arrays returned by your [generator function](https://rdrr.io/cran/keras/man/fit_generator.html).

Comment: I dont think type or length are the pb since the code works on a windows computer